# Configuring the SuiteBar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, suite-links, suitebar

[image]

Beside hiding the items in the bar or the bar, what about replacing the items from the Suitebar. Thinking somtehing like placing the no.2 in no.1 drop-down. Or something like, just having one bar like in 2010, and then when activating edit, or show ribbon, then the extra one will show.

It just fills alot with thoes two bars on a intranet site, and random users does not need to use the ribbon, just follow and share, and that could be placed somwhere more discrete, like in the no1. drop-down.

Is this, hard-core development?

Answer (score 1):

Both are different controls, looks like you have to write some kind of logic to merge them. Below is indiival customization of both( Suite Bar and Promoted Actions Links)

Promoted Action links (i.e. Share,Follow,SYNC,EDIT) are displayed below the **blue Delta Suite bar** (SkyDrive,Sites,NewsFeed). In a typical SharePoint 2013 site, these links are displayed using the new **“Promoted Actions Delegate Control”**. To add and remove any link in the Promoted Actions, you would need to Override the Promoted Actions Delegate Control and deploy the solution in your farm.No out-of-box way to add these links is available.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/19/add-links-to-promoted-actions-sharefollowsync-in-sharepoint-2013/

As a part of a new UI in SharePoint 2013, Microsoft has added a new Links Bar also known as “Suite bar” that displays Links NewsFeed, SkyDrive and Sites. These links are displayed using **“SuiteLinksDelegate”** Delegate Control which has also been Introduced inSharePoint 2013. Adding, Removing and Customizing these Links however is not easy. You can only add and remove these links by Overriding **“SuiteLinksDelegate”** Delegate Control with a feature solution created in Visual studio.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: That was awesome, thank you. I do have some knowledge to edit the suite-bar, but was not clear how to play with the Promoted Action links. Thanks, I will look at the links. As I understand you, then they just override the standard/default associated delegate contorls, so no changes in the Master page is needed after deploying.